# Sample similar to Population

Tags: machine-learning, sampling, sample-size, population

I have 100,000 customers, each customer has a few variables associated with them, separated into 100 groups.  I want to find a sample of 10 groups that best represents the entire 100 groups.  What are my best options for doing this?

Should I just look at overall mean and st. dev for the variables and find the 10 groups that have the closest match?

Comment: What do you  need this for? Look at the aspects which are important for you, and then define similarity using them.

Answer (score 4):

Technically, simple random sampling from the population will produce a sample that is representative. That just means picking each individual with equal probability.

Alternately if you *know* some basic demographic information about the sample, you can draw a stratified sample which is *not* representative. However, stratified samples can be weighted to produce more efficient estimates of population attributes than in the simple-random samples.

What you are describing: selecting individuals whose characteristics are close to the population mean will *not* produce a representative sample and will probably bias all your results in a way that weighting cannot easily address. As an example, if you divide your customers according to volume/frequency to inspect the things they buy, the mode purchasing pattern will probably be high frequency / low volume customers. These customers, however, may not be the major revenue contributor for your company. You are omitting the purchases of low frequency / high volume purchasers whose demands may actually be different, whose desired products are different, and whose cost preferences determine whether they move their *entire* batch purchases to another vendor or stay with you.

Comment: (+1) very good point emphasizing common misconception about "representative" sampling! Maybe you could provide a short example or description of *why* selecting "average" individuals would lead to biased sample -- it would make your answer even more valuable.